# How to achieve Server-To-Server communitcation with Flask

Tags: php, flask

I have a REST service which should render the the data before the REST implementation. So when I send the data to the server he will render and then he will pass the results to the REST interface in other server. Can this type of workflow be realized?

Comment: Thanks for explain my question better then me.